# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/accumulo/core/client/Instance

Tags: hadoop, noclassdeffounderror, accumulo

I'm using small program to write data into Accumulo.

Program worked when added jars manually. But, when build with maven, with the same version's used from manual it throws:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/accumulo/core/client/Instance.

How would I resolve it?

Comment: Need more information, post your code and pom.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your job is going to be run on all of the nodes in your MR network.  You'll need the appropriate jars on all of the nodes in order for it to work.

Another approach, as you have noticed, is to just include everything into one uber jar, which contains everything that you need.  That way when your job gets shipped to each node, you'll have everything you need.  One way to accomplish this with maven is through the use of plugins:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/hadoop-job.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Inside of your hadoop-job.xml you might have

```
<assembly>
  <id>job</id>
  <formats>
   <format>jar</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
      <unpack>false</unpack>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
      <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>${groupId}:${artifactId}</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </dependencySet>
    <dependencySet>
      <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
      <unpack>true</unpack>
      <includes>
        <include>${groupId}:${artifactId}</include>
      </includes>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

More information about this plugin may be found at http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/

Comment: I'm trying to include .sh files along with .jar file. So, i tried different ways and ended up with a fail. How would i wrap the jar and shell files into a tar.

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to do, you might want to look into http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to download the `accumulo-core.jar` and add it to your classpath.

Comment: @srikanth How do you run your program and show your file structrue please. And which version of `accumulo` do you use?

Comment: I'm using mapreduce to do the insertion job. A Driver.java, Mapper.java, Connector.java(Singleton). I use accumulo-1.5.1. I run using 'hadoop jar name.jar package.classname args1 args2'. Exception throws in Mapper, on line where i initiate the call for singleton Connector.java